# Best SQL browser for HSQLDB?

Tags: java, sql, browser, hsqldb, sqlbrowser

Whats the best browser tool for HSQLDB databases?

Comment: There is no "the best" tool. Look for one, that fullfills most of your requirements.

Comment: Execute Query is pretty good also http://executequery.org/screenshots

Comment: This question has moved to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/fast-to-set-up-hsqldb-database-management-gui

Answer (score 83, accepted):

HSQL has built-in GUI query tool called [Database manager](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/dbm-chapt.html). In the directory of the database files run:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

and then setting the config to:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseName
```

Allowed me to edit what I needed in a really convenient way.

Comment: As I found out the hard way, the database name has be the filename without its extension. E.g. databasefile.data should be jdbc:hsqldb:file:databasefile

Comment: Using `org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing` will get you a slightly nicer user interface.

Comment: Great solution for simple browsing operations... but I'm unable to perform other simmple operations, like to copy (for pasting into notepad) the content of a single record...

Comment: @sherb: Caveat: it's also much slower than the AWT interface though.

Comment: note: when running the bat file to show the manager, use the standalone type

Answer (score 35):

DBeaver works very nicely:

http://dbeaver.jkiss.org

Also, SQuirreL is always a safe bet for any database:

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net

Meanwhile, IntelliJ has decent database tooling, too

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: This answer is best than the accepted if you also need to modify your data.

Comment: Just a note - don't forget specifying the exact database file name when using the DBeaver HSQL Embeded connection.

Comment: +1 for DBeaver; really useful particularly if you develop in Eclipse (you can add it as a plugin into your current IDE)

Answer (score 12):

I've had good experience with SQL Workbench/J. Some of the best features compared to other tools: Auto completion for tables and columns in SQL statements, Code formatting etc.

Check out the features on the project site:

http://www.sql-workbench.net/

Comment: I agree, SQLWorkbench is a very good tool, light, easy to use, but full of interesting (and even rare) functionnalities (schema comparaison for example). I mostly use only this one nowadays, even instead of Eclipse integrated database viewer plugin.

Comment: I just tried it. Looks good but you have to get the JDBC path to the HSQLDB database file exactly right otherwise it will fail to open it silently i.e. no error messages are shown and it looks like it has opened something even though the path is completely bogus.

Comment: I just realized that what threw me is if you don't get the path to the existing file correct it will create a new, empty, database for you at the path you gave.