# How do I determine the default HSQL database connection information in Talend Studio?

Tags: hsqldb, talend

I am new to Talend Studio.  I am doing data profiling using Talend Studio enterprise version 7.3.  Generating PDF reports has gone smoothly.

Our group would like to produce some output that is different than what is automatically provided, so we would like to query the underlying reporting database.  If I go to the Generated Report Settings pane, there is a Database Connection Settings area with a Db Type of HSQL.  Clicking the Check button causes a popup that says "Connection successful and Datamart well configured", as shown below.

[image]

Great!  Unfortunately, I have not been able to find the name of the database, so that I could connect to it and inspect it using an IDE.  For example, I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990864/best-sql-browser-for-hsqldb) that I should be able to connect to the HSQL database using its built-in GUI query tool called DatabaseManager like so:

```
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
```

and then setting the config to:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:databaseName
```

But what is the "databaseName"?  Is it specified in a properties file or XML file somewhere?

Comment: There is a DB connection tab somewhere. You need to report what it shows for its settings.

Comment: @fredt -  Window -> Show View... Data Explorer  -> Connections shows nothing for HSQL.